# Html link to another port

Tags: html, raspberry-pi

I want to make a "mainpage" for my raspberry, with links. I want one of the links to bind to an another port. The RPI is on `192.168.1.125` and I want to use port `8080`

I tried this: `<a href=192.168.1.125:8080>My Awesome Link</a>`, but it opens `192.168.1.125/192.168.1.125:8080` and not `192.168.1.125:8080`.

My other tries what also didn't worked:

- `<a href="192.168.1.125:8080">`
- `<a href="/192.168.1.125:8080">`

What's the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefix the URL with `http://` for addresses not on the same website.

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.125:8080">My Awesome Link</a>
```

You can also use the "[protocol-relative URL](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)" by prepending two slashes, though that's probably outside the scope of your task.  It'll use HTTP or HTTPS based on which protocol the current page is using.

```
<a href="//192.168.1.125:8080">My Awesome Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you it's worked :) I can accept your answer in 10 minutes